# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_internal

Tags: python

I am making a 2d platforming game in Pygame.

'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_internal''

This error is occuring on this line:
self.sprites.add(playerbanner)

```
     class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

         def __init__(self,classname,movementspeed,jumpheight,damage,x,y,sprites,platforms,bullets,banner,spawndirection):
            super().__init__()
            self.classname=classname
            self.speed=movementspeed
            self.height=jumpheight
            self.damage=damage
            self.x=x
            self.y=y

            self.banner=banner
            self.startdirectionspawn=spawndirection

            self.walking=False
            self.jumping=False
            self.currentframe=0
            self.lastupdate=0

            self.velocityx=0
            self.velocityy=0
            self.accelerationy=0

            self.lastpress=1

            self.loadframes(classname)

            self.image=self.stationary

            self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center=(self.x,self.y)
            self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

            self.sprites=sprites
            self.platforms=platforms
            self.bullets=bullets 

        def countdown(self):
            gamecountdown(6)


        def updateposition(self,hit,jump):

            if self.accelerationy<0:
                hit=False

            if self.accelerationy!=0:
                jump=False

            if hit==False:
                self.accelerationy+=0.1

            if jump==True:
                self.accelerationy=-15     

            if hit==True:
                self.velocityy=0
                self.velocityx=0
                self.accelerationy=0

            pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
                self.velocityx=-self.speed
                self.animate('left')
                self.lastpress='a'

            if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
                self.velocityx=self.speed
                self.animate('right')
                self.lastpress='d'

            if not pressed[pygame.K_a] and not pressed[pygame.K_d]:
                if self.lastpress=='d':
                    self.image=self.stationary

                elif self.lastpress=='a':
                    self.image=self.stationarya

            self.x+=self.velocityx
            self.y+=self.velocityy + (0.2*self.accelerationy)

            self.rect.center=(self.x,self.y)

            playerbanner=messagedisplay(self.banner,BLACK,self.x-15,self.y-50, 30, 30, 'smallfont')
            self.sprites.add(playerbanner)


            self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
            pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to get a 'player 1' to print above the player's head. When I do not put it into a group, it still prints, but flickers on and off.

The group print statements are called from another file.

Comment: `add_internal` doesn't even appear in the code you've posted. Please include the full traceback.

Comment: @roganjosh Well, that's the problem - I don't really understand why it is needed or what it even is. The reason it is not in my code is because it isn't there at all.

Comment: we don't understand where it is either because you haven't posted the complete traceback as I requested. Just because it doesn't appear in the code that you actually wrote, doesn't mean that it's not integral to the running of your script: that code exists somewhere in one of the modules that you have imported (or something similar)